# How to start/resume an Oracle VirtualBox and immediately after pause it?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I'd like to start or resume a Virtual Machine, and as soon as I can control the mouse put it in pause mode (host+p).

This way, I can start the vm and other tasks but not have the vm drain system resources, yet I can use the VM at will by unpausing it. Like with firefox, start it into memory, so its available when you need it.

I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle VirtualBox can be managed through the commandline entirely so it is possible to write a script that does just that.

Create a batch file, for example `Start VM.cmd` and put the following content in it:

```
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"

start "" VirtualBox.exe --startvm "Virtual Machine 1"
set var=""
echo Waiting for the virtualbox to complete its startup routine.
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('vboxmanage list runningvms') do set "var=%%A"
set var2=%var:"=%
if "%var2%"=="Virtual Machine 1 {d325eda7-8abc-4083-9bc5-d41b3acf0ba5}" goto next
goto loop

:next

VBoxManage controlvm "Virtual Machine 1" pause
```

Change the 2nd line to the path where you have VirtualBox installed. Additionally change the name and guid of the virtual machine to match yours in tha various locations in your script.

You can do this by opening a command prompt and type in the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage list vms
```

Copy that entire row and paste it in your batchfile, then remove the surrounding quotes (") from the Virtual Machine name.

For example, `"Virtual Machine 1" {d325eda7-8abc-4083-9bc5-d41b3acf0ba5}` becomes `Virtual Machine 1 {d325eda7-8abc-4083-9bc5-d41b3acf0ba5}`

## Short educational story

I do a few things in this script, and I'll explain the pitfalls and why I do them.

I use start to launch the virtual machine to ensure that the script continues to run while the VM is started. If I didn't, the script would wait for the VM to be terminated before it'd continue.

Next I `set var=""` This is technically not necessary if you start the script by doubleclicking on the icon from explorer, but if you use command prompt and you run it multiple times, it will only work the first time.

Next, I create a loop. In the loop I query which VM's are running. If the VM that I'm interested in is indeed running, we break the loop. Now, I had to perform a trick here to make this work. Because the vm returns contains a " it would think the " was in the if statement earlier and causes the script to not work. To counteract this, I remove any " from the %var% and store this as var2. This is required because if no VM is running, %var% is not updated. Would I use `set var=%var:"=%` it would work once, and on the next loop breaks the script, terminating it with an error.

Finally after the VM runs, it does an exact match and breaks the loop. The pause command then is sent to the VM and it will pause the VM as soon as it can. Its not instant, but the delay is minimal, and given that vboxmanage list running vms returns it, the system knows it will accept the command.